# How to put "+" and "x" after \hline in tabular, and reducing space?

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to write "+" and "x" after \hline, and I want reducing the space between number and number.

From this
[image]

become

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, top=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
            &&&&6&0&0&1\\
            &&&&&2&7&2\\
            \hline$\times$
            &&&1&4&0&0&2\\
            &&5&2&0&0&7&$\cdot$\\
            &1&4&0&0&2&$\cdot$&$\cdot$\\
            \hline$+$
            &2&1&3&4&2&7&2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I like this from a mathematical point of view, but…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{multiplication}[1]
 {% #1 = number of digits in the result
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}%
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \newcommand{\size}{#1}%
  \mathcode`*=\cdot
  \begin{array}{*{#1}{>{\strut}c} c}
 }
 {\end{array}}
\newcommand{\dividerline}[1]{% #1 = symbol
  \multicolumn{\size}{c}{%
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
                   depth  -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt\relax
    \hfill\kern0pt
  }%
  & \smash{#1} \\
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{multiplication}{7}
  &   &   & 6 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  &   &   &   & 2 & 7 & 2 \\ \dividerline{\times}
  &   & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
  & 5 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 7 & * \\
1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 2 & * & * \\ \dividerline{+}
2 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 7 & 2
\end{multiplication}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A “slightly” more complicated version that allows you not to do calculations error like in the above scheme. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplication}{O{c}mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  % some initializations
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \mathcode`*=\cdot
  % the main command
  \ensuremath { \ongky_multiply:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
  % end the group
  \group_end:
 }

\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
\seq_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
\int_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_size_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ongky_multiply:nnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl { \int_eval:n { #2 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl { \int_eval:n { #3 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl { \int_eval:n { (#2)*(#3) } }
  \int_set:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_size_int { \tl_count:N \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl }
  % create the numbers to sum up (padding with * on the right)
  \int_step_inline:nn { \tl_count:N \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
     {
      \int_eval:n
       {
        \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl *
        \tl_item:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl { -##1 }
       }
      \prg_replicate:nn { ##1 - 1 } { * }
     }
   }
  % start building the body of the array
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \__ongky_divider:n { \times } }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
   {
    \__ongky_multiply_put:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \__ongky_divider:n { + } }
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
  % print the array
  \begin{array}[#1]{ *{\l__ongky_multiply_size_int}{>{\strut}c} c }
  \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_temp_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \l__ongky_multiply_size_int - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { {} }
    #1
   }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l__ongky_multiply_temp_tl \__ongky_multiply_put_item:n
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put_item:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { #1 & }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__ongky_divider:n
 {
  \multicolumn{\l__ongky_multiply_size_int}{c}{%
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
                   depth  -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt\relax
    \hfill\kern0pt
  }%
  & \smash{#1} \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiplication{6001}{272}

\bigskip

\multiplication[t]{32}{444}\qquad
\multiplication[t]{444}{32}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more efficient code using `\tl_build` experimental features:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplication}{O{c}mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  % some initializations
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \mathcode`*=\cdot
  % the main command
  \ensuremath { \ongky_multiply:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
  % end the group
  \group_end:
 }

\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
\seq_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
\int_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_size_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ongky_multiply:nnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl { \int_eval:n { #2 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl { \int_eval:n { #3 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl { \int_eval:n { (#2)*(#3) } }
  \int_set:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_size_int { \tl_count:N \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl }
  % create the numbers to sum up (padding with * on the right)
  \int_step_inline:nn { \tl_count:N \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
     {
      \int_eval:n
       {
        \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl *
        \tl_item:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl { -##1 }
       }
      \prg_replicate:nn { ##1 - 1 } { * }
     }
   }
  % start building the body of the array
  \tl_build_begin:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \__ongky_divider:n { \times } }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
   {
    \__ongky_multiply_put:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \__ongky_divider:n { + } }
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
  \tl_build_end:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  % print the array
  \begin{array}[#1]{ *{\l__ongky_multiply_size_int}{>{\strut}c} c }
  \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_temp_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \l__ongky_multiply_size_int - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { {} }
    #1
   }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l__ongky_multiply_temp_tl \__ongky_multiply_put_item:n
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put_item:n
 {
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { #1 & }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__ongky_divider:n
 {
  \multicolumn{\l__ongky_multiply_size_int}{c}{%
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
                   depth  -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt\relax
    \hfill\kern0pt
  }%
  & \smash{#1} \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiplication{6001}{272}

\bigskip

\multiplication[t]{32}{444}\qquad
\multiplication[t]{444}{32}

\end{document}
```

## Season’s gift: a version that allows any base from 2 to 36

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplication}{O{c}mmO{10}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  % some initializations
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \mathcode`*=\cdot
  % dirty trick for letters
  \sbox0{$\mathtt{\int_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_int {\mathgroup}}$}
  \int_step_inline:nnn { `A } { `Z }
   {
    \mathcode ##1=\int_eval:n { \g_tmpa_int * 16 * 16 + ##1 }
   }
  % the main command
  \ensuremath { \ongky_multiply:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } }
  % end the group
  \group_end:
 }

\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
\seq_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
\int_new:N \l__ongky_multiply_size_int

\cs_new:Nn \__ongky_multiply_base:nnn
 {
  \int_to_Base:nn { \int_from_base:nn { #1 } { #3 } * \int_from_base:nn { #2 } { #3 } } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ongky_multiply_base:nnn { ff }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ongky_multiply:nnnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
   {
    \__ongky_multiply_base:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
   }
  \int_set:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_size_int { \tl_count:N \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl }
  % create the numbers to sum up (padding with * on the right)
  \int_step_inline:nn { \tl_count:N \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
     {
      \__ongky_multiply_base:ffn
       { \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl }
       { \tl_item:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl { -##1 } }
       { #4 }
      \prg_replicate:nn { ##1 - 1 } { * }
     }
   }
  % start building the body of the array
  \tl_build_begin:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_first_tl
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_second_tl
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \__ongky_divider:n { \times } }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_summands_seq
   {
    \__ongky_multiply_put:n { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \__ongky_divider:n { + } }
  \__ongky_multiply_put:V \l__ongky_multiply_result_tl
  \tl_build_end:N \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  % print the array
  \begin{array}[#1]{ *{\l__ongky_multiply_size_int}{>{\strut}c} c }
  \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__ongky_multiply_temp_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn { \l__ongky_multiply_size_int - \tl_count:n { #1 } } { {} }
    #1
   }
  \tl_map_function:NN \l__ongky_multiply_temp_tl \__ongky_multiply_put_item:n
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { \\ }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__ongky_multiply_put_item:n
 {
  \tl_build_put_right:Nn \l__ongky_multiply_output_tl { #1 & }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__ongky_divider:n
 {
  \multicolumn{\l__ongky_multiply_size_int}{c}{%
    \leaders\hrule height \dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2+0.2pt\relax
                   depth  -\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-0.2pt\relax
    \hfill\kern0pt
  }%
  & \smash{#1} \\
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiplication{6001}{272}\qquad
\multiplication{6001}{272}[8]\qquad
\multiplication{6001}{272}[16]\qquad
\multiplication{6001}{272}[36]

\bigskip

\multiplication[t]{32}{444}\qquad
\multiplication[t]{444}{32}\qquad
\multiplication[t]{32}{444}[5]\qquad
\multiplication[t]{444}{32}[5]\qquad

\end{document}
```

In the first row the multiplications are in base 10, 8, 16 and 36 respectively.

In the second row the first two are in base 10, the last two in base 5.

[image]

Comment: By the way, that is multiplication between two octal numbers, not decimal numbers. But, thanks for your help.

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya I put online a new version you may enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

TikZ is overkilling here, just simply use `multirow`s and `\cline`s.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, top=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}    
        \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
            &&&6&0&0&1\\
            &&&&2&7&2&\multirow{2}{*}[-.2pt]{$\times$}\\            
            \cline{1-7}
            &&1&4&0&0&2\\
            &5&2&0&0&7&$\cdot$\\
            1&4&0&0&2&$\cdot$&$\cdot$&\multirow{2}{*}[-.2pt]{$+$}\\
            \cline{1-7}
            2&1&3&4&2&7&2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @OngkyDennyWijaya You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a proposal. Decreasing the distance is standard. In order to place the symbols, I am loading Ti*k*Z. Loading Ti*k*Z for only this may be overkill.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, top=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{*{8}{@{\,}c}}
            &&&&6&0&0&1\\
            &&&&&2&7&\tikzmarknode{2a}{2}\\
            \hline %$\times$
            &&&1&4&0&0&\tikzmarknode{2b}{2}\\
            &&5&2&0&0&7&$\cdot$\\
            &1&4&0&0&2&$\cdot$&$\tikzmarknode{dot}{\cdot}$\\
            \hline%$+$
            &2&1&3&4&2&7&\tikzmarknode{2c}{2}
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
         \node at ([xshift=5mm]$(2a.south)!0.6!(2b.north)$) {$\times$};
         \node at ([xshift=5mm]$(dot.south)!0.6!(2c.north)$) {$+$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. As a "good housekeeping" measure, maybe also replace `left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, top=2.00cm` with `margin=2cm`?

Answer (score 3):

To snug up the numerals, all you need to do is add the instruction `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}`. If the result looks too tight, maybe try `\setlength\tabcolsep{0.25pt}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{letter}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}  % <-- new
        \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
            &&&&6&0&0&1\\
            &&&&&2&7&2\\
            \hline$\times$
            &&&1&4&0&0&2\\
            &&5&2&0&0&7&$\cdot$\\
            &1&4&0&0&2&$\cdot$&$\cdot$\\
            \hline$+$
            &2&1&3&4&2&7&2
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: for this code, plus and times sign are not in the right of line, but thanks for your answer.